# How to mock service from controller using revel framework in golang?

Tags: go, revel

I am writing unit test for project written in revel framework. Revel itself  provides testing framework but its more towards BDD test type. So I started with go test. 
The MyController.go file looks like below

```
type MyController struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func (c MyController) HealthCheckHandler() revel.Result {
   responseBody, status := service.HealthService()
   c.Response.Status = status
   return c.RenderJSON(responseBody)
 }
```

MyController_test.go file

```
func TestHealth(t *testing.T ){

myController := &MyController{
    &revel.Controller{
        Response:&revel.Response{
            Status:200,
        },
    }   ,
    }
 res := myController.HealthCheckHandler()

}
```

How can I mock HealthService() method ? If I use Interface-Composition way for mocking then how routes will inject the interface? As routes.go is self generated file.

Comment: `service` seems to be global, make it instead a field on `MyController` and define it as an interface with one method `HealthService`. Then in your test file implement a service mock type that satisfies that interface and inside your test initialize that mock and set it as the service field on the `myController` instance.

Comment: This will be able to mock the service. But how will routes will initialize the service ? As routes.go and main.go files are self generated.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using the revel test framework it's working fine.

for your issue try this, inject your service on the structure, instead of calling it directly, that will allow you to mock it in a test.

Not beautifull but will do the trick.

```
type MyController struct {
    *revel.Controller
    Initialized   bool
    HealthService func() ([]byte, int)
}

func (t *MyController) init() {
    if !t.Initialized {
        t.Initialized = true
        t.HealthService = func() ([]byte, int) {
            return service.HealthService()
        }
    }
}

func (c MyController) HealthCheckHandler() revel.Result {
    c.init()

    responseBody, status := c.HealthService()
    c.Response.Status = status
    return c.RenderJSON(responseBody)
}

func TestHealth(t *testing.T) {
    mockFunction := func() ([]byte, int) {
        return []byte(`"message":"you custom body here"`), http.StatusOK
    }

    myController := &MyController{
        &revel.Controller{
            Response: &revel.Response{
                Status: 200,
            },
        },
        HealthService: mockFunction,
        Initialized:   true,
    }

    res := myController.HealthCheckHandler()
}
```

Comment: You said it as well, this looks less than ideal. I'm scared there is no way to do proper DI.